# How can I escape the brackets so they are seen as literal characters

Tags: entities

I am using clientside validation along with the field UI module in a Drupal 7 site to request some custom input fields on user registration. I need to set some custom error messages using the clientside validation `modulename_clientside_validation_rule_alter()` function. The problem is, the field UI module creates fields with brackets in the name attribute like so: `field_first_name[und][0][value]`. When I use this as the first argument of `_clientside_validation_set_required()`, the proper error message is not being shown. I believe this is because the brackets are not seen as part of the string. How can I make the brackets literally brackets and not look like an array to drupal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't the brackets—I was able to set the rule by referencing the nested `#name` and `#value` keys:

```
_clientside_validation_set_required(
      $element['field_first_name']['und']['0']['value']['#name'],
      $element['field_first_name']['und']['0']['value']['#title'],
      isset($element['field_first_name']['und']['0']['value']['#required']) ? $element['field_first_name']['und']['0']['value']['#required'] : FALSE,
      $js_rules,
      t('Please enter your @field_name.', array('@field_name' => strtolower($element['field_first_name']['und']['0']['value']['#title'])))
    );
```